# Slax on NTFS (GRUB) with Changes Saved Natively

Tags: ntfs, multi-boot, grub2, slax

I have Slax 7 and Windows XP running on the same (ntfs) partition - woohoo! I still have a few issues, holes in my understanding:

1. Slax apparently saves all "changes" to a single file `C:\slax\changes\changes.dat`. I don't want this, want normal persistence so that (e.g.) the Linux file system (/usr, /etc etc) is be visible in Windows. How can I switch off this single-file persistence and have the Linux root map to my `C:\slax\root`? Setting `changes=/slax/save` has no effect.
2. When I make changes to `/etc/fstab`and reboot to Linux the changes are gone. How can I automount /dev/sda1 each time Slax starts?
3. In general, where are all the parameters (max_loop, init, from...) specified after `kernel` documented? Are they distro specific?
4. I can see and browse my HDD in Dolphin but it's not showing up in `mount`. How is that achieved and where would I find it in the console (`cd ?`)
5. What (physically) is the `aufs` entry mounted at `/` referring to?

Comment: little question, how did you install slax on a ntfs disk with windows xp?